# Java Split string containing pipe and new line characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split the below string and put in map - the below data may be in single line or multiple line. I want to avoid "\n" at starting of keys name in maps

```
    user.Split-A=1|
    user.Split-B=1|
    user.Data-C=532|
```

But the map is created with \nuser.Split-A=1, \nuser.Split-B=1, \nuser.Data-C=532 and \n

Here is the code -

```
        Map valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
//Splitting string containing pipe
        for (String string : spHeader.split("\\|")) { 
            String[] mapPair = string.split("=");
            valueMap.put(mapPair[0], mapPair[1]);
        }
```

Please check if this can be done.

Comment: Than in regex include `\n` as a option, and remove `\n` from the key value before inserting to the map....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix is to call [`String#trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()):

```
valueMap.put(mapPair[0].trim(), mapPair[1].trim());
```

Of course it can be taken care of using a better regex which wouldn't even capture `EOL` in your matched strings.

You can use this regex for matching keys and values delimited by `=` without capturing `|` or `\n` or `=`:

```
([^=|\s]+)=([^=|\s]+)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mY5xH5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
\|\n?
```

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("\\|\\n?");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "user.Split-A=1|\nuser.Split-B=1|\nuser.Data-C=532|\n";

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        REGEX_PATTERN.split(input)
    )); // prints "[user.Split-A=1, user.Split-B=1, user.Data-C=532]"

}
```